# Ant design Table component accessibility react js

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, antd

I'm working with Ant design table component : https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection.
I'm trying to implement the accessibility features in my table component, but the table component doesn't have the configuration for accessibility. Also the table caption tag is missing from the component which is required for screen readers.

Also for adding the aria attributes to the checkboxes/radio for row selection, I have to use `getCheckboxProps` property of `rowSelection` prop.

```
<Table
    rowSelection={{
      type: "checkbox",
      getCheckboxProps: (record) => ({
          "aria-label": "row selection"
        })
      }}
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
/>
```

But this method does not add the aria attribute to the checkbox in header for selection all rows.

[image]

codesandbox link for above example : https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-antd41610-forked-qpfow?file=/index.js

any way to make this table component accessible friendly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution to solve that problem. However, In github
Somebody asked the same question as you and they discussed a lot. I will leave link below you can check it too.

I am using antd and bootstrap together. I haven't tried yet but I think you can implement accessibility of bootstrap to antd table. I know that sounds silly but maybe this will work you can't know if you don't try. I am a beginner react coder btw so I just tried to help as much as I can. I hope this link will help. Greetings
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22343